Are these two groups $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ under addition isomorphic or not?
I am a beginner at ring theory, and after studying the polynomial rings, I have known about the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x], \mathbb{Q}[x], \mathbb{R}[x]$ which forms a group under addition.
After knowing that, I decided to find various kind of isomorphism with the infinite additive groups $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$
I saw $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}$ as the later is cyclic but the former is not
But in case of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, I did not find anything. All of them are seeming to be same, but I don't think they will be isomorphic. Abelian, Non cyclic, order of elements all I have tried.
$\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has a non cyclic subgroup $\mathbb{Z}[x],\quad\mathbb{Q}$ has also non cyclic subgroups like $\{\frac{m}{2^n}\}$.
So, I am not getting the conclusion.
I know a result that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Q^*}$ and that comes from the product of primes, it was a very tough one.
Also can you say about $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}$, as additive groups?

Note: the additive group $\mathbb Z[x]$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of the positive rationals.  See, e.g., this question

It's easy to show the following proposition:

Let $A, B$ be divisible and torsion-free abelian groups, then they are canonically $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces, and any group homomorphism $\rho:A\rightarrow B$ is $\mathbb Q$-linear.

Therefore if $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q[x]$ are isomorphic as additive abelian groups, then they are isomorphic as $\mathbb Q$-linear spaces which is not true as they have different dimensions over $\mathbb Q$.
Similarly, $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R[x]$ are isomorphic as abelian groups, because they are isomorphic as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces, as their Hamel basis over $\mathbb Q$ must have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

How easy is it to construct/demonstrate an isomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R[x]$?

@J.W.Tanner, I'd say it's not straightforward, particularly for someone who's just beginning to study ring theory and so presumably does not know much nontrivial set theory/cardinal arithmetic. It requires a nontrivial invocation of the axiom of choice, for one, so it's fundamentally not explicit. Maybe the "nicest" proof is by taking a $\Bbb Q$-basis of $\Bbb R$ and showing it's of size $\mathfrak c$ by cardinal arithmetic. Then you get $\Bbb R \cong \Bbb Q^{\oplus \mathfrak c} \cong \Bbb (\Bbb Q^{\oplus \mathfrak c})^{\oplus \aleph_0} \cong \Bbb R^{\oplus \aleph_0} \cong \Bbb R[x]$.

I suppose you can avoid the cardinal arithmetic using this fact (extending this particular linearly set to a basis with Zorn's lemma), together with the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem.

I tried to prove the isomorphism, but instead of it, I have got that there can not be any isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.
If possible let, $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}$ be an isomorphism.
Since $x\in\mathbb{Q}[x],$ $\phi(x)=\frac{a}{b}$ for some $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}.$
Similarly, $x^2\in\mathbb{Q}[x], \phi(x^2)=\frac{c}{d}$ for some $\frac{c}{d}\in\mathbb{Q}.$
Since $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q},$ the polynomial $bcx-adx^2\in\mathbb{Q}[x].$
Now, \begin{align*}
\phi(bcx-adx^2) & = \phi(bcx)-\phi(adx^2)\text{ [since, $\phi$ is homomorphism.]}\\
                & = \phi(x+x+\cdots+x)[bc \text{ times}]-\phi(x^2+x^2+\cdots+x^2)[ad \text{ times}]\\
                & = bc\cdot\phi(x)-ad\cdot\phi(x^2)\text{ [Using homomorphism.]}\\
                & = bc\cdot\frac{a}{b}-ad\cdot\frac{c}{d}\\
                & = ac-ac=0
\end{align*}
Also, by the property of isomorphism, identity of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ will map to identity of $\mathbb{Q}.$
i.e., $\phi(0)=0.$
So, two distinct elements have the same image$\implies\phi$ is not one-one.$\implies\phi$ is not an isomorphism.

Check the answer
